# How to zoom with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm drawing a simple bar chart with d3, and I have an x axis setup and have the brush setup so that I can brush to "select" a group of the bars.  I would like to then drill down and scale the chart to contain only these bars.  The following code works and the colors of the bars inside and touched by the brush turn the right color, but I can't make the thing zoom.

I have looked at this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 and a bunch of other stuff and just cannot figure it out.

[Here is a fiddle, can someone show me how to simply zoom the darn thing?](https://jsfiddle.net/mbaranski/xk0j85mb/)

```
var brush;

function go3()
{
    var dataset = [];
    var m = 40;
    var count = 500;
    dataset.push(m);
    for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {           //Loop 25 times
        var newNumber = Math.random() * m;  //New random number (0-30)
        dataset.push(newNumber);             //Add new number to array
    }

    margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 10},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom


    w = width;
    h = height;

    yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(dataset)]).range([0, h * .95]);
    xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, w])
        .domain([0, w]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");

    console.log("Max: " + d3.max(dataset));

    svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w  + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    ;

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("stroke", "grey")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr("fill", "#FFFFFF")
        .classed("main-container", true);

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("stroke", "grey")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0)
        .attr("fill", "#EEFFEE")
        .attr("x", margin.left)
        .attr("y", margin.top)
        .classed("brushable-container", true)
    ;

    xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (h + margin.top) + ")")
        .call(xAxis)

    padding=2;

    rects = svg.append("g").selectAll(".brushable")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .classed("brushable", true);


    brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .x(xScale)
        .on("brush", brushmove)
        .on("brushend", brushend);

    context = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "context")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(brush)
        .selectAll('rect')
        .attr('height', h);

    barWidth = w / dataset.length;
    console.log("Width: " + barWidth);
    rects
        .attr("width", 4)
        .attr("height", function(d, i){ return yScale(d)})
        .attr("stroke", "yellow")
        .attr("stroke-width", .3)
        .attr("x", function(d, i){ return (i * barWidth + margin.left) })
        .attr("y", function(d, i){ return h - yScale(d) + margin.top} )
    ;
}

function brushend(){
    var extent = brush.extent();
    var min = extent[0] >= extent[1] ? extent[1] : extent[0];
    var max = extent[0] >= extent[1] ? extent[0] : extent[1];

    var lolobb = d3.selectAll("rect.brushable");
    var lob = lolobb[0];
    console.log(min + " - " + max);
    var i = 0;
    while( i <  lob.length ){
        var bbb = lob[i];
        try {
            var p = parseFloat(bbb.attributes.x.value);
            if(min <= p && max >= p) {
                d3.select(bbb).attr("fill", "#00FF00");
            } else {
                d3.select(bbb).attr("fill", "#000000");
            }
            i++;
        } catch(r) {
            console.log("BBB");
            console.log(bbb);
            console.log("Error with " + i);
            console.log(typeof(bbb));
            console.log(r);
        }
    }
    console.log(min + " - " + max);
    console.log(lolobb);
}

function brushmove() {
    var extent = brush.extent();
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle example doesn't seem to be working for me (could be my end though). Anyways did you take a look at the [github doc on Zooming](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior)? I was able to get zooming to work on my d3 application that way. They have a [basic zooming example here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999).

Comment: Never mind, I was able to get it working by a [separate fiddle with the same code](http://jsfiddle.net/a3ubzjgL/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding calling a `zoom` function on `"body"`, you can do so by doing:

```
svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w  + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
;
```

The zooming part is:

```
    .append("g")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
```

Then add the `zoom()` function:

```
function zoom() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

[**Here is a Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/a3ubzjgL/1/). Use the scroll wheel to zoom.

Comment: I see, what I really want is to zoom when someone finishes brushing.  When you check out the fiddle you can see that the "selected" rectangles change color (via a style change).  I want it to zoom as well.  Not with a scroll wheel

Comment: @mikeb The scroll wheel is default when zooming, is there a reason you don't want to use it? Would basic scaling by the center of the graph work? Or would you like to scale based on the selected area?

Comment: Yes, the reason is I have it setup so that you can select a section of the bar chart and I want to zoom to that section.  It might be 10% of the chart at the very bottom or it might be the top 80% or it might be the middle 2%.  I have the "brush" setup to "select" the section to zoom, and I want to zoom to it.

Comment: @mikeb It seems your might want to do something a bit more complex than zooming. Would zooming to it just be zooming to the center of that selection. Or have that selection get "bigger" and the other things "smaller"? Also, how would you go back to normal?

Comment: OK, I have an x-axis of 1->500 with a bunch of vertical bars.  A user selects an area with a "brush" and the selection starts at point 100 and ends at point 200 on the x-axis.  What I want to do is *only show bars between 100 and 200* while zooming in.  I don't know what else to call it, because it seems like "zooming" to me.

Comment: @mikeb Ah Ok I see what you mean, yeah it's not exactly zooming.

Comment: Actually, it's the exact definition of zooming.

Comment: @mikeb I mean it's not basic zooming, it's a bit more advanced and has displaying and hiding certain items.